# Bake vertex colors to texture from mesh

Tags: vertex-colors

This has been asked before but I can't find the solution now. The solution was something about going into blender render, setting the bake type to vertex colors and then just baking but I'm just getting pure white bake. Obviously I'm missing some steps... or something. I do most of my work in cycles so I think the issue could be something to do with the nodes. Do the nodes or materials need to be set up in certain way?

Baking vertex colors has been working just fine before. I just did this a couple of days ago but something has now changed and I can't get any my vertex colors to bake anymore. I just get white.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setup material like this, Using emission node makes it fast:

[image]

You can get vertex color data here:

[image]

In bake options chose "Emit"

[image]

Comment: I just get white bake with this.

Comment: show your setup

Comment: If I make new blend that thing you showed works. But on my blend file it doesn't.

Comment: Make a screenshot and post it in question body

Comment: Oh my god I'm such a total idiot! I had my image editor set to show alpha and not the diffuse channels (those little icons next to the pivot options in image editor). I was looking at the alpha channel instead of the rgb channels...

Comment: Note for newbies: the "Col" in the Attribute box is important, and is case sensitive.

Comment: For blender 2.9: switch to cycles rendering, replace the material output node in the shading wokspace, use the Vertex Color node indead of the Col one menionted here. Oh and don't forget to have your object already UV mapped and a texture image selected.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried baking in Blender 3.2 and I think it's important to note that in the Object Data Properties under *Color Attributes* the vertex color setup should look like this:

[image: vert color setup]

I had to create a new color attribute using the `+` button, because the default one was set to Face Corner* and *Byte Color* which gave me a completely black bake.