# blender 2.8 obj or x3d import texture usage

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, import

I want to import obj or x3d files that have a texture encoded as vertex colors. In blender 2.79 my workflow is following the description of Jan in his answer described here: [How to display and use Vertex Color from OBJ model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90890/how-to-display-and-use-vertex-color-from-obj-model/90945#comment248475_90945).
(Basically: Selecting the "material" tab in the properties, adding a new material to the object and checking the box "vertex color paint")

This works nicely for blender 2.79. However, I would like to get this to work in blender 2.8. Though I am able to display my object with vertex colors in the viewer (by simply setting the "object interaction mode" to "vertex paint mode") blender 2.8 won't render my vertex colors.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with a material node setup by adding an attribute input node and setting the *Name* value to **Col** and plug that into the shader of your choice.  I've used a diffuse BSDF shader here, but you can pipe the color to any node color input you so desire.

[image: Node setup for vertex color]

You could also this by baking the vertex colors out to a texture.

Please refer to the following question for a how to guide.

[Bake vertex colors to texture from mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117728/bake-vertex-colors-to-texture-from-mesh)

Comment: whohoo! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about taking materials from a website to blender, on poliigon you can just drag it right into blender. I'm not sure if it'll work on other websites, but it supposed to work with poliigon.

Comment: no, I am talking about formats that encode the colors along the 3d structures (surface, triangles and such, comparable to POVray format). I generate these 3D shapes from stereo camera images which contain the colors. Unfortunately the software to calculate these objects has raytracing not implemented. Thus I thought to export the structures with the colors included. This works for POVray and blender 2.78. But blender 2.8 is much more user friendly than those. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I can answer that.